# Не понимаю что будет выведено в консоль?

Tags: java

Что будет выведено в консоль? Дали задание... а там одни ошибки, все красное... что капец, кто понимает - подскажите плиз))

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ABC().printStrToLowerCase();
            new ABC().setStr2("Hello");
            new ABC().printSrt2ToLowerCase();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
    }
}

class ABC {

    public String str = "ABC";
    public String str2;

    public ABC() {
        str = "CBA";
    }

    void printStrToLowerCase() {
        System.out.println(str.toLowerCase());
    }

    void printSrt2ToLowerCase() {
        System.out.println(str2.toLowerCase());
    }

    void setStr2(String newValue) {
        str2 = newValue;
    }
}
```

Что будет выведено в консоль?

```
public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            GenericForTest<String> genericOne;
            genericOne = new GenericForTest("Hello");
            GenericForTest<StringBuilder> genericTwo;
            genericTwo = new GenericForTest<>(new StringBuilder("World"));

            String stringOne = genericOne.getValue();
            String stringTwo = genericTwo.toString();
            System.out.println(stringOne + " " + stringTwo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }

    }
}

class GenericForTest<T> {

    public T value;

    public GenericForTest(T value) {
        this.value = value;

    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Если уж не пройтись по шагам по коду, то запустить и проверить уж точно можно без подсказок со стороны. Но как минимум вы получите ошибку, поскольку `System.out.println` и других конструкций в C# не существует в отличии от Java (ошиблись меткой?).

Comment: Я попробывал пройтись по шагам... но там одни ошибки(( И возможно из за того что я пробывал C#, а мне прислали на Java задание((( А если это джава, то что будет на консоле? Или как понять если только студия

Answer (score 1):

Если под рукой нет компилятора Java, то в крайнем случае можно попробовать онлайн компилятор для Java. По крайней мере код полностью рабочий. В первом случае вы получите вывод и ошибку т.к. у нового экземпляра не установлен `str2`.

```
cba
FAIL
```

Во втором случае

```
Hello
```

Но в любом случае лучше понимать, откуда это взялось т.к. мой ответ на ваши знаний совершенно не повлияет. А для этого желательно уметь пройтись по шагам с помощью компилятора.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку про онлайн компилятор